# xargs -I % /path/ %

Tags: linux, xargs

If torrent has a problem like deleted data on hard drive in id column it has number like "ID*".

I want to filter IDs of torrents in torrent list which have a symbol "*" at the end of id(LIKE ID* or 1*,2*,25*) and delete them from torrent list.

Full command is:

```
/usr/bin/transmission-remote 127.0.0.1:9091 --auth ts:ts -l | grep "*" | awk '{print $1}' \ 
| xargs  -n 1 -I  % /usr/bin/transmission-remote 127.0.0.1:9091 --auth ts:ts -t% -r
```

I expected result:

```
 /usr/bin/transmission-remote 127.0.0.1:9091 --auth ts:ts -t ID* -r
```

But something went wrong.
Transmission said that:

```
127.0.0.1:9091/transmission/rpc/ responded: "success"
```

But torrent didn't delete from list.

How I can see the final result to compare with expected?

Comment: Try putting `echo` in there?

Comment: Try running your original command → grep → awk chain, without piping it into the final xargs. When I try, it gives no output. (Probably because the grep is bad, "\*" by itself is meaningless and possibly an error). I replaced the grep *and* awk with a single `awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1}'`, which seems to give better results, but I don't know if they're the results you want. (It just prints all IDs)

Comment: I tried that. And I saw next:
21*
22*
Because with this torrents are problems. I mentioned that If torrent has a problem in id column it has number like "XX*". Problem like deleted data on hard drive.

Comment: ID :25*    Done :  100%      Have: 19.06 MB      ETA:  Done   Up:  0.0 Down: 0.0  Status:Stopped   Name:DAEMON.exe

Comment: Result I need is IDs of torrents with symbol "\*" at the end.    
After that i add this IDs to command:
  /usr/bin/transmission-remote 127.0.0.1:9091 --auth ts:ts -t ID* -r

Answer (score 0):

To get IDs :

```
transmission-remote -l | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}' | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

The full command :

```
transmission-remote -l | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}' | grep -o '[0-9]*' | tr "\\n" "," | xargs -n 1 -I \% transmission-remote -t \% -r
```

Done and done (:
With the added improvement of using "tr" to join all torrent IDs and avoid running everything in a loop ( Transmission-RPC is extremely resource intensive to call repeatedly )